# Spring xml config mixed java config

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have created a basic Spring MVC app, when I config xml like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"

       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.3.xsd
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.3.xsd
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.3.xsd
" >
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.hell"/>
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/pages/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

everything goes well, the controller and the view mapped via @RequestMapping, but when I add this empty class and build

```
@Configuration
public class Config {
}
```

the routing does not work, it say 404 error.
then I must add `<mvc:annotation-config/>` or `@EnableWebMVC`, the routing then works.
can someone explain this, I think this is so weird.
edit:
this is my web.xml to config DispatcherServlet

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>springmvc</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>springmvc</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: You can bootstrap your JavaConfig from XML with a ``ConfigurationPostProcessor`` if you really want to mix both configuration styles.

Answer (score 0):

I have search the Internet and I find that the `context:component-scan` tell the Spring to scan for the `@Configuration` classes, so maybe this is the answer to my question, anyone pls correct me.

Answer (score 0):

@Configuration is used for Java based spring configuration,so I think if you are doing configuration of your beans through Java code then your xml configuration is limited .I will suggest to stick with one approach,that will make your code easy to.maintain

Comment: yes, I just learning Spring and want to try everything, 
but in my example, the Spring doesn't need `mvc:annotation-driven` to map with the view, but when use the `@Configuration` it requires the `mvc:annotation-driven` to run